List of basic identities for the hypergeometric function
I'm learning about the hypergeometric function and want a list of basic identities/formulae that it satisfies.
The Wikipedia page lists some good identities, but fails to list some basic results such as
$$F(a,b,c,0)=1$$
and
$$F(a,b,c,1) = \frac{\Gamma(c-b-a) \Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(c-b) \Gamma(c-a)}$$
for $\Re(c-b) > \Re(a)$.
As someone who hasn't used the HGF much before, I still have to look up identities such at the above $F(a,b,c,1)$ one frequently, and it's possible that there are other basic identities that I am unaware of.
I'm struggling to find a more useful list anywhere. Can somebody please provide one?

Here is huge summary of identities:
https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4
and transformations:
https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8

also here.
